# Will transactions wait for each other or work parallel if we talk about a table with a unique index in InnoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, unique-index

I have one table in InnoDB engine looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   `unique_str` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE `sample`
   ADD UNIQUE `unique_str_index` (`unique_str`);
```

As you can see this table has a unique index on column "unique_str".

For example, I want to run two scripts with transactions one-by-one.

```
//First script, i use pdo for connection
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('first')");
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('violate_str')");
sleep(50); //I'll start second script here
$pdo->commit();
```

I'll start the second script when the first script is sleeping within 50 seconds.

```
//Second script
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('third')");
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('violate_str')"); 
$pdo->commit();
```

In second script PHP will be stuck on the very first string with "insert" command and wait while the transaction in the first script would be committed. When the first script waked up from sleep and committed the transaction, two new strings would be created in the table ('first' and 'violate_str') and the second script would start work again: the second script would go through two inserts, but on the second insert ('violate_str') would be generated an exception.

My question is "**why PHP is waiting until the first transaction is completed and isn't working this time? Is MySQL blocking the second transaction? Why?**". I think I have some misunderstanding of principles transactions work. I thought that transactions would be created one-by-one and the second transaction wouldn't be blocked.

Comment: You sure MySQL made the table as innoDB and not MyISAM? i advice you to add `Engine = InnoDB` to the `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: *"why PHP is waiting until the first transaction is completed and isn't working this time? Is MySQL blocking the second transaction?Why?"* it's the way InnoDB engine works assuming the table are really running under the InnoDB engine *"InnoDB checks UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints row-by-row. When performing foreign key checks, InnoDB sets shared row-level locks on child or parent records it has to look at. InnoDB checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not deferred to transaction commit"* [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Yes, the table running under InnoDB, I checked.
Here is command output "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'sample'
sample InnoDB 10 Dynamic 1 16384 16384 0 0 0 2 2019-05-04 15:15:21 2019-05-04 19:14:01 NULL utf8_general_ci NULL   0 N"

Comment: innoDB more or less locks the complete unique key to make sure the records are still unique between transactions which actually is not "allowed" by ANSI/ISO SQL standards when using transactions.  *"According to the SQL standard, the default behavior should be deferred checking. That is, constraints are only checked after the entire SQL statement has been processed, . Until InnoDB implements deferred constraint checking,"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second script is waiting for the *second* insert, not the first insert.

If I test your code with echo statements:

```
//First script, i use pdo for connection
$pdo->beginTransaction();
echo "begin done\n";
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('first')");
echo "insert('first') done\n";
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('violate_str')");
echo "insert('violate_str') done\n";
sleep(50); //I'll start second script here
echo "sleep done\n";
$pdo->commit();
echo "commit done\n";

//Second script
$pdo->beginTransaction();
echo "begin done\n";
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('third')");
echo "insert('third') done\n";
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO sample (unique_str) VALUES('violate_str')");
echo "insert('violate_str') done\n";
$pdo->commit();
echo "commit done\n";
```

I see the output from the first script:

```
begin done
insert('first') done
insert('violate_str') done
```

Now it has started its sleep, so I run the second script and see this output immediately:

```
begin done
insert('third') done
```

It waits at this point. So we know it completed one insert without waiting. It is waiting on the second insert, the one that is in conflict with the insert of 'violate_str'. That's because the first script has already created that entry in the unique index, even though it hasn't committed it. It still holds a lock on that value in the index, so the second script has to wait for that lock.

Once the sleep ends, the first script commits, and outputs:

```
sleep done
commit done
```

Then the second script can acquire the lock, and attempt to insert the row. But unfortunately, the first script already inserted that value and committed it, so we get a duplicate key violation.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1062 Duplicate entry 'violate_str' for key 'unique_str'
```

If the first script were to do `rollback()` instead of `commit()` then it releases its lock and undoes the insert. This allows the second script to finish *and* insert the contentious value freely.